# filter pandas dataframe list column that matches element in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which holds nhl players and the positions they are eligible to play.

`players = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['Alex Ovechkin', 'Leon Draisaitl', 'Evander Kane', 'Sydney Crosby'], "position": [['LW'], ['C', 'LW'], ['LW', 'RW'], ['C']], })`

```
    name    position
0   Alex Ovechkin   [LW]
1   Leon Draisaitl  [C, LW]
2   Evander Kane    [LW, RW]
3   Sydney Crosby   [C]
```

I have a list which specifies which positions I want to select from the dataframe.

`positions_to_see = ['LW','RW']`

Result should be all but Sydney Crosby as none of his positions ('C') are in the positions_to_see list.

Looking for help how I select the players for which at least one of their eligible positions is in that positions_to_see list?

I tried to do an intersection from the list column to that list, but I get errors about dimension size.  It's not projecting my list for each row.

thanks,
Craig

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can `apply` on `position` column to negate the set disjoint using `isdisjoint`, then use this boolean masking to filter out the dataframe

```py
players[~players['position'].apply(lambda x: set(positions_to_see).isdisjoint(x))]
             name  position
0   Alex Ovechkin      [LW]
1  Leon Draisaitl   [C, LW]
2    Evander Kane  [LW, RW]
```

If you are interested in individual positions as well that are in `positions_to_see` list, then `explode` the position column, and use `isin` (`in` for DataFrame.query) operator:

```py
>>> players.explode('position').query('position in @positions_to_see')
             name position
0   Alex Ovechkin       LW
1  Leon Draisaitl       LW
2    Evander Kane       LW
2    Evander Kane       RW
```

You can also take the set intersection, but then order may not persist.

Answer (score -1):

One way using `pandas.Series.apply`.

Note that `set(positions_to_see)` is *more* useful if `positions_to_see` were lengthy since it makes membership test `O(1)` (doesn't mean it's useless).

```
l = set(positions_to_see)
players[players["position"].apply(lambda x: any(i in l for i in x))]
```

`any` also has a benefit of short-circuit as opposed to `not set.isdisjoint` or `bool(set.intersection)`

Output:

```
             name  position
0   Alex Ovechkin      [LW]
1  Leon Draisaitl   [C, LW]
2    Evander Kane  [LW, RW]
```